# Form showing nothing. using CefSharp with Windows form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am trying to show a webpage in a form using C#. I am using CefSharp to show the webpage (as I would like to test & learn how it works). But since I have worked only on inbuilt webbrowser, I have no idea how to get started with CefSharp(Finding it difficult to get any tutorials). I tried to write this code which executes but the form shows nothing in it. Where am I going wrong ?
Here is my Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace chrometest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            var test = new       CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser("http://www.google.com")
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            };
            this.Controls.Add(test);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Edit :
I tried to run the example from https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/cefsharp/41/CefSharp.WinForms.Example
When I try to build the solution, it shows a dialog box saying "Restoring Nuget Package cef.redist.x64 3.2454.1317" with a progresss bar which takes hell lot of time to complete but never completes and after sometime it hangs.[image: Here is a screenshot]

Please help what should I do to get the example running.

Answer (score 1):

The `CefSharp` project has a few different examples as part of the main project.

**Basic Example using Nuget**

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

**More Advanced Examples**

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/cefsharp/41/CefSharp.WinForms.Example

When you installed the project using `Nuget` it should have opened a `Readme.txt` file, it contains a lot of useful information.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/41/NuGet/Readme.txt

In the context of `WinForms` there's a few tutorials

http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/if-you-like-it-put-an-html5-ui-on-it.html
http://thechriskent.com/2014/08/18/embedded-chromium-in-winforms/

For those reading this looking for `WPF`, there's

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/881315/Display-HTML-in-WPF-and-CefSharp-Tutorial-Part
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/887148/Display-HTML-in-WPF-and-CefSharp-Tutorial-Part

**More Links**

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.Tutorial

http://thechriskent.com/category/net/cefsharp/

Comment: Thanks, I refered "https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/cefsharp/41/CefSharp.WinForms.Example" But it shows me a dialog showing "Restoring Nuget Package cef.redist.x64 3.2454.1317" it takes too long and then it freezes the Visual studio which makes it 'Not Responding'. How do I get the example code running ?

Comment: How fast is your internet? Combined the pages will be about `80mb` to download. So it may just take some time. Make sure you have the latest `VS` updates and `Nuget` is the latest version. If that doesn't work then look at doing a command line `nuget` restore.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But everything is as it was earlier. I updated VS to the latest, Installed latest Nuget version, and tried. Same thing happened the VS freezed again. I also tried command line nuget restore referring https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore#command-line-package-restore . The problem still persists !!! Does CefSharp even work ??? I am frustated ! I think it is of no Use if I can't get its example running ! But I wanted to learn it. Please help ...

Comment: What makes you think the problem your having has anything to do with `CefSharp`? Is there an error message from the command line nuget restore? What VS (including Service Pack) are you using? Operating system?